# How do I use the new Saved State Module of ViewModel

Tags: android, android-viewmodel, android-savedstate

I'm using lifecycle version 2.2.0-rc03 and the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate) and articles found don't even list the correct class name or constructor arguments. I think I have to get the ViewModel instance through something like this

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, SavedStateViewModelFactory(requireActivity().application, savedStateRegistryOwner))
            .get(SelectedTracksViewModel::class.java)
```

but I can't figure out the SavedStateRegistryOwner.

Can someone give a simple example of how to create the saved state ViewModel instance and the correct way to save and restore a value in the ViewModel?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

For using Saved State module for View Model you have to add the `androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate` dependency to your project. This example has been written based on version `1.0.0-rc03`.

Please add the following line to your project Gradle file:
`implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:1.0.0-rc03'`

**ViewModel implementation:**

```
class SavedStateViewModel(private val state: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    val liveData = state.getLiveData("liveData", Random.nextInt().toString())

    fun saveState() {
        state.set("liveData", liveData.value)
    }
}
```

**Activity implementation:**

```
class SavedStateActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: SavedStateViewModel;

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val binding: ActivityStateBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_state)

        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, SavedStateViewModelFactory(this.application, this)).get(SavedStateViewModel::class.java)

        binding.viewModel = viewModel
        binding.lifecycleOwner = this
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        if(::viewModel.isInitialized)
            viewModel.saveState()

        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }
}
```

I have tested this code and it works fine.

Comment: You don't need to manually set the live data key from `onSaveInstanceState` if you already obtained the LiveData as `savedStateHandle.getLiveData`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I commented `state.set("liveData", liveDate.value)` line and tested with `lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate` version 2.2.0, but unfortunately it didn't work for me. Would you please provide working sample code?

Comment: Technically you don't need your `saveState` method entirely if you use `savedStateHandle.getLiveData`

Comment: and it's critical to call `viewModel.saveState()` before `super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)`, otherwise it won't work for some reason that I don't know yet

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't agree with this. (Maybe just a little too late). VM saved state is already lifecycle aware. You don't need to attach the views LifeCycle to the VM they are already there.

Answer (score 6):

I am adding an answer to this old post just in case someone might find it useful.

I managed to do it as follows:

- Add the following dependency to your "build.gradle (Module: app)" file

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

- Add `savedState: SavedStateHandle` property to the constructor of the `ViewModel`

```
class SelectedTracksViewModel(private val savedState: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {

    companion object {
        private const val SAVED_TRACK_INDEX = "savedTrackIndex"
    }

    private var trackIndex: Int
      set(value) {
        field = value
        // Simply update the savedState every time your saved property changes
        savedState.set(SAVED_TRACK_INDEX, value)
      }

    init {
        trackIndex = savedState.get<Int>(SAVED_TRACK_INDEX) ?: 0
    }

    fun moveToNextTrack() {
        trackIndex++ 
        // Initially I was updating savedState here - now moved to setter
        
        // Some more code here
    }    
}
```

Finally in the activity/fragment

```
    private val selectedTracksViewModel: SelectedTracksViewModel by lazy {
        ViewModelProvider(this).get(SelectedTracksViewModel::class.java)
    }
```

And that's it. No need for `SavedStateViewModelFactory`, simply add the `savedState` property to your `ViewModel` constructor and update it when tracked properties change. Everything else works as if you're not using `savedState: SavedStateHandle` and this way is very similar to the traditional `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle)` in activities/fragments.

**Update:** Initially I was updating `savedState` after changing `trackIndex`. This means one has to update `savedState` *every time* saved properties are changed. This is a huge potential future bug if one forgets to add that line. A better and more robust pattern is to update the `savedState` in the setter of the property.

Comment: If you pass another parameter to the ViewModel (like Api reference), you will still need a `ViewModelFactory` class as:

in Activity:

`val viewModelFactory = SwapiViewModelFactory(ApiInterface.getInstance())`
`val viewModel: TransportationListViewModel by lazy {`
`ViewModelProvider(this, viewModelFactory,[TransportationListViewModel::class.java]`
`}`

[ViewModelFactory with Parameter Example](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/5157474/193959968-cec5f94d-f732-4911-9bfb-9b42396924fe.png)

Comment: @RealityExpander A single `SavedStateHandle` parameter is a special case for which you do not need a `ViewModelFactory`. Have a look at the examples in the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel-savedstate). Also the api has now changed so in the fragment/activity you would use `private val selectedTracksViewModel: SelectedTracksViewModel by viewModels()`

Comment: But what if you need to add another parameter to the ViewModel. Is there a way to do that using the `by viewModels()` method?

Comment: @RealityExpander Sorry I might have misunderstood your comment: Yes if you have any other parameter then you would need to either use a `ViewModelFactory` or a dependency injection library (e.g. hilt, koin, etc)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I understand you want to create View model with spec constructor.
You can use `ViewModelProvider.Factory`.

```
viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(state)
            .get(SelectedTracksViewModel::class.java)
```

**example of ViewModelFactory**

```
public class SavedStateViewModelFactory {

    public static <E> ViewModelProvider.Factory create(State state){

        return new ViewModelProvider.Factory() {
            @NonNull
            @Override
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(SelectedTracksViewModel.class)) {
                    return (T) new SelectedTracksViewModel<>(state);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class");
                }
            }
        };
    }

}
```